# MySQL insert random items up to 10,000 times?

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure how this is possible or if its an easy solutions I'm not sure of or even the name of it.

I'm looking to insert 10,000 rows into a database with three columns for a "map" area of 100x100:

```
-----------------
| x | y | type |
-----------------
| 1 | 1 |    1 |
-----------------
| 1 | 2 |    1 |
-----------------
| 1 | 3 |    2 |
-----------------
| 1 | 4 |    3 |
-----------------
| 1 | 5 |    4 |
-----------------
| 1 | 6 |    4 |
-----------------
| 1 | 7 |    2 |
-----------------
| 1 | 8 |    2 |
-----------------
| 1 | 9 |    1 |
-----------------
| 2 | 1 |    2 |
-----------------
| 2 | 2 |    1 |
```

Basically X column goes up to 100 Y column goes up to 100 so there will be X:1 Y:1 and X:100 Y:100 and all of the variations (10,000) Along with this the type column needs to be a random number between 1 and 4. (this would be ideal if I could set a percentage of each number e.g 1 25% of the 10,000 2 is 15%, 3 is 40% and 4 is 20%).

Is there a way to do this with MySQL to generate this some how rather than writing up an insert for 10,000 rows? Or would I be best off writing some form of PHP script to execute and insert this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a couple of foreach loops?

Comment: You would be best off writing some form of PHP script to execute and insert that. Make the try and post your code to take a look at it.

Comment: I don't know how you are using this data exactly but this seems like a highly inefficient way to store this data.  I would make your table structure something like `X, Ys` and then the data would would like `1, 1123442212...`  This way you will only have 100 rows in your database.  If you want to explain a little bit more on how you are using this data Id be happy suggest how to format your database beyond my initial thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. PHP might be the route I'll have to take. @cmorrissey I'm making a basic map that's 100x100 squares. So all in all there are 10,000 squares that will have 4 different "types".

Comment: @KojoSlayer I would defiantly move away from your current approach of storing each square as its own row in your database ... doing it this way if you wanted to render the whole map ... your selecting 10k rows, which is the most inefficient way to do this.

Comment: @cmorrissey the most i'll be selecting is 4-8 at any one time would it still be inefficient then?

Comment: @KojoSlayer will they always be adjacent squares?

Comment: @cmorrissey the most that will be shown will be: (Excuse the crude dawing): http://imgur.com/hG1tb9Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$values = [];

for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++)
{
    for ($y = 1; $y <= 100; $y++)
    {
        $rand = mt_rand(1, 100);

        switch (true)
        {
            case ($rand <= 25):  $i = 1; break;
            case ($rand <= 40):  $i = 2; break;
            case ($rand <= 80):  $i = 3; break;
            case ($rand <= 100): $i = 4; break;
        }

        $values[] = sprintf("(%d, %d, %d)", intval($x), intval($y), intval($i));
    }
}

$sql = "Insert Into table (x, y, type) Values" . implode(',', $values);

echo $sql;
```

Comment: If you add a `var_dump( $values );` you can display all the data (+1).

Comment: This would only create *approximately* 25% 1s etc. See my answer below if you want *exact* distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with a PHP script.

First, you could create an array of 2500 1s, 1500 2s, 4000 3s and 2000 4s. Then use two foreach loops (for X and Y) and take a number from a random index in the array, removing the element from it.

You want code?

```
<?php
$values = array_fill(0, 2500, 1)
        + array_fill(2500, 1500, 2)
        + array_fill(4000, 4000, 3)
        + array_fill(8000, 2000, 4);

$statements = [];
foreach (range(1, 100) as $x) {
    foreach (range(1, 100) as $y) {
        $v = $values[mt_rand(0, count($values) - 1)];
        $statements[] = "INSERT INTO table (x, y, type) values ($x, $y, $v);";
    }
}

echo implode("\n", $statements);
```

Comment: why you ask it in mysql

Answer (score 0):

or this. you can do everything with the nr. INSERT INTO newtab .....

```
SELECT a.a*10000 + b.a*1000 + c.a*100 + d.a*10 + e.a AS nr FROM (
 SELECT 0  a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 ) AS a
 CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT 0  a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
) AS b
 CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT 0  a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
) AS c
 CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT 0  a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
) AS d
 CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT 0  a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
) AS e
ORDER BY nr;
```

Comment: Wow, I have no idea whether I should upvote this for being an interesting answer or down vote it for the "OMG WHAT IS THAT!" side of things :P.

Comment: Wait, I just ran it and I only see one column with numbers from 0 to 500.

Comment: @Jon Stirling - start then you see the loop in MySQL or use MariaDB there you can do it in one line SELECT seq from seq_1_to_10000;